# javascript select parent element's child

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I want to do something like this:

```
<td class="repeats">     
    <img src="a.png"/>
    <span onmouseover="this.parentNode.info.src='images/b.png'" 
          onmouseout ="this.parentNode.info.src='images/a.png'">
          text here
    </span>
</td>
```

Without using an ID or JQuery (ideally) I need a way of selecting the image in the current cell. How can this be achieved?

I only want to change the current cell, as opposed to all cells with the same class.

Comment: In css you can use this selector `.repeats img:hover` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `previousSibling`:

```
<td class="repeats">     
    <img src="a.png"/>
    <span onmouseover="this.previousSibling.src='images/b.png'" 
          onmouseout ="this.previousSibling.src='images/a.png'">
          text here
    </span>
</td>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling

---

Or you can use `parentNode.childNodes[0]`:

```
<span onmouseover="this.parentNode.childNodes[0].src='images/b.png'" 
    onmouseout ="this.parentNode.childNodes[0].src='images/a.png'">
    text here
</span>
```

Comment: Nice one, previous sibling is perfect for my needs!

Comment: Be careful: `previousSibling` can return a text node on some browsers instead of the `img` element. See the note at http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/previousSibling.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
$('td[class="repeats"]').children().filter('Img').dosomething();
```